# Mongo command to add a field to all documents in a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This code appends a boolean column to all documents in the `birds` collection.

```
db.birds
  .find()
  .snapshot()
  .forEach(function(el) {
    el.hi = true
    db.birds.save(el)
  })
```

Here's how the command is run in production.

```
mongo db_stuff/db_name -u username -p password theScript.js
```

This command runs very slowly.  Should I look into the [`$set` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) or something else that will speed this up?

Comment: What does your db look like? Size? Columns? Types? A schema is usually required when asking about db optimisations.

Answer (score -1):

This is a lot faster:

```
db. birds.updateMany(
   {},
   { $set:
      {
        hi: true
      }
   }
)
```

Comment: That's great! But this is not a review :-(

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.